# Aplicar uma thumbnail

Tags: c#

Como criar um arquivo qualquer e nele fazer com que o Windows Explorer reconheça uma thumbnail nesse arquivo, sem modifica-lo nem altera-lo.

Exemplo:

Em um arquivo **.PNG** o arquivo não é modificado e o Windows Explore gera automaticamente uma thumbnail.

Isso também acontece em arquivos do Microsoft Office 2010 etc.

Então como seria feito isso em C# ?

Comment: Você quer criar um arquivo em um formato que seja reconhecido por estes softwares? Ou quer fazer que estes software reconheçam um formato de arquivo seu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é dificil de fazer, graças ao SharpShell, que pode ser baixado no NUGET. Tive que fazer isso para um projeto ha um tempo atrás. Utilizei um artigo do Code Project. Vou dar uma breve explicação, mas no site você encontra uma explicação completa (em ingles) e o link para download do exemplo.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563114/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Thumbnail-Handlers

Basicamente o que vc deverá fazer é criar um componente COM. Este componente, será registrado no windows, e o explorer poderá utiliza-lo para renderizar seus thumbnails.

Crie um novo projeto no c#, e adicione as referencias para `System.Windows.Forms` e `System.Drawing`. Abra o Package Manager Console e digite `Install-Package SharpShell`. Com todas as referencias vinculadas ao projeto, crie uma nova classe e copie o exemplo abaixo. Lembrando que todo este códgio foi retirado do artigo do codeproject.

```
using SharpShell.Attributes;
using SharpShell.SharpThumbnailHandler;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TxtThumbnailHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The TxtThumbnailHandler is a ThumbnailHandler for text files.
    /// </summary>
    [ComVisible(true)] //Torna ele um componente "visível" para a COM
    [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.FileExtension, ".txt")] // Associa este coponente ao tipo de associação de Extensão de Arquivos, e informa que o tipo de arquivo é neste caso, o txt.
    public class TxtThumbnailHandler : SharpThumbnailHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TxtThumbnailHandler"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public TxtThumbnailHandler()
        {
            //  Create our lazy objects.
            lazyThumbnailFont = new Lazy<Font>(() => new Font("Courier New", 12f));
            lazyThumbnailTextBrush = new Lazy<Brush>(() => new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the thumbnail image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the image that should be returned.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The image for the thumbnail.
        /// </returns>
        protected override Bitmap GetThumbnailImage(uint width)
        {
            //  Tenta abrir uma stream com o StreamReader.
            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(SelectedItemStream))
                {
                    //  Read up to ten lines of text.
                    var previewLines = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (line == null)
                            break;
                        previewLines.Add(line);
                    }

                    //  Chama a função que Realiza a geração do thumbnail.
                    return CreateThumbnailForText(previewLines, width);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
               // Faz algo, tipo gravar num log
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the thumbnail for text, using the provided preview lines.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="previewLines">The preview lines.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A thumbnail for the text.
        /// </returns>
        private Bitmap CreateThumbnailForText(IEnumerable<string> previewLines, uint width)
        {
            //  Tamanho do Bitmap
            var thumbnailSize = new Size((int)width, (int)width);

            //  Cria o bitmap.
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            //  Cria um objeto graphics para manipular o bitmap
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                //  Habilita o antialiasing
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

                // Desenha o fundo do thumbnail
                // Repare que aqui a imagem do fundo do thumbnail está armazenada em um arquivo de recursos
                graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Page, 0, 0, thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height);

                //  Create offsets for the text.
                var xOffset = width * 0.2f;
                var yOffset = width * 0.3f;
                var yLimit = width - yOffset;

                graphics.Clip = new Region(new RectangleF(xOffset, yOffset, thumbnailSize.Width - (xOffset * 2), thumbnailSize.Height - width * .1f));

                //  Renderiza cada linha do texto
                foreach (var line in previewLines)
                {
                    graphics.DrawString(line, lazyThumbnailFont.Value, lazyThumbnailTextBrush.Value, xOffset, yOffset);
                    yOffset += 14f;
                    if (yOffset + 14f > yLimit)
                        break;
                }
            }

            //  Retorna o bitmap
            return bitmap;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The lazy thumbnail font.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Lazy<Font> lazyThumbnailFont;

        /// <summary>
        /// The lazy thumbnail text brush.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Lazy<Brush> lazyThumbnailTextBrush;
    }
}
```

Como vc pode ler no comentário acima, é necessário carregar a imagem de fundo do thumbnail em um arquivo de recurso, e utiliza-lo na linha assinalada.

Feito isso, é necessário dar um "Nome Forte" pra seu projeto. 
- No solution explorer, clique com o botão direito sobre o projeto
 e clique em propriedades
- Clique na aba Assintauras(Signing)
- Marque a opção Assinar o Assembly(Sign the Assembly)
- No dropdown abaixo selecione new. 
- Uma caixa de díalogo será aberta. 
- Informe um nome para seu assembly.
- Desmarque a opção de senha e clique em OK.

Feito isso, basta compilar seu código e testar.

Para testar sua extensão de shel, utilize o Server Manager, que acompanha o sharpshell tools. Voce também pode baixar o programa no repositório do sharpshell:

https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.